# seas package output r

Tags: r, regression, arima

I am using the seas package in R for forecasting sales
One of the outputs of the regression is weekday coefficient, I am not sure what this is , since I am inputing the data on a monthly basis

Can anyone advise what does weekday mean?

This is the summary on the model output[image: x13 output]

Comment: Why don't you include your output? Either with your data- or with sample data if your data is confidential.

Comment: `seas` has some of the automatic X-13 options turned on by default, like AIC tests for the automatic inclusion of trading day effects. My guess is what X-13 calls "td1coef" or "td1coefnolpyear", which is a regressor that accounts for the different number of weekdays in a given month over time. To be sure you should have `seas` save the full X-13 output and take a look in the ".out" file.